# joint savings account requiring three signatures

Tags: savings-account, joint-account, death

Savings account requiring three (and) signatures for withdrawals.  Does the (and) change to (or) upon the death of one of the signatories? Wells Fargo bank changed the requirement for two signatures to allow one signature after the death of one of the signatories.

Comment: what country are you in? Who inherits the money from the deceased?

Answer (score 4):

That would not be automatic. If the Account requires ALL [or Survivors] for withdrawal, upon death of one of the Signatories, there would some paperwork [death certificate, etc] that needs to be submitted to the Bank to change the Signatories. Until such time, withdrawal cannot happen from the account.